# changing one item in a generic list will change All other with same value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object Array, and a specific List. 
Each object in this object array should work on this string separately and return a number:

```
{
  var nT = 0;
  var nF = 0;

  #region Irisdataset

  Irisdataset[] dataobj = new Irisdataset[150];

  #endregion

  foreach (var data in dataobj)
  {
    bool ChroValue = false;

    List<List<string>> localchro = new List<List<string>>(chromosome);
    ChroValue = ExpValueForEachData(data, localchro);
    if (ChroValue == true)
      nT++;
    else
    {
      nF++;
    }
  }
  return 1.1
}
```

I have created a localcopy of chromosome and then passed it to the function, but it didn't work. And, after executing "ExpValueForEachData" one time, the chromosome changed.
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing what's called a shallow copy when in this scenario you want to do a deep copy.

Try the following:

```
List<List<string>> localchro = new List<List<string>>();

foreach(List<string> list in chromosome)
{
    // chromosome is holding references to the address of a List<string>
    // You want to create a new copy of the data within the reference
    // This is a deep copy
    localchro.Add(new List<string>(list));
}
```